# How to do injection in Angular Module imports

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ng-modules

I'm importing a configurable module from an external library like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ThirdPartyModule.forRoot(MY_CONFIG)]
})
```

Problem is that MY_CONFIG is not static and makes use of a service in order to define its value, so I would use a factory to build up the module configuration like this:

```js
@Injectable
class ConfigFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService){}

  public config(){
    return {
      someconfigvalue: this.configService.buildSomeConfigValue()
    };
  }
}
```

In this case I should rewrite the import like

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ThirdPartyModule.forRoot(configFactory.config())]
})
```

But I don't know how to inject the config factory.

I know that if I had this situation with a provider I could use a factory provider.

Is there something similar for the module imports? Can I use a factory for importing a module? Or is there another solution to this problem?

*P.S. please note that I cannot change the code for the ThirdPartyModule.*

Comment: I'm afraid you can't inject anything to the decorator. Just create an instance of `config` manually and pass it to `forRoot`.

Comment: @KenBekov In order to create an instance of config I need to use the injector because the ConfigFactory needs an injected ConfigService. How can I do that?